# Concordion.Net not writing specifications html to BaseOutputDirectory defined in <spec>.config

Tags: bdd, specifications, concordion

I've been trying to start using Concordion.Net.  I've managed to get NUnit to run the Concordion.Net tests.  The issue I have is that the output HTML is generated in the `TEMP` folder, not where I specify based on the `<dllname>.config`.

I followed instructions in the 'Configuration' section of Concordion.Net (http://concordion.org/dotnet/Configuration.html), but still didn't manage to get it working.

I am testing out with the `Kickstart.Spec` project in the tutorial.  I've added a `Kickstart.Spec.config` file, with the below contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Specification>
  <BaseOutputDirectory path="C:\concordion-test" />
</Specification>
```

I've set the file to 'Copy Always' and tried with both setting it as an `Embeddable Resource` or as the default `Content`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description it should work. I tried to do the same steps as you described and received the output files in C:\concordion-test. Perhaps we can figure out what the problem is, when I describe step by step how my setup looks like:

1) after downloading the kickstart-projects (I tried both: through git as well as downloading the ZIP file from the github/releases), I added a config file to the Kickstart.Spec project in Visual Studio 2013. The file structure looks like that:

[image]
[image]

2) in the properties of the new config file Kickstart.Spec.config, I set "Copy always" and left the Build Action to the default value "None":

[image]

3) when I rebuild the entire solution the config file is copied with all the dll files to the output directory Kickstart.Spec\bin\Debug:

[image]

4) when I run the tests with NUnit, the report files are placed in the folder C:\concordion-test:

[image]

I hope this description helps to get it up and running for you as well.
Please, don't hesitate to ask further questions.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps the NUnit settings can help to get the Concordion reports placed in C:\concordion-net. I am using the following settings:

1) I use the Visual Studio support and open the sln file or the csproj file in the NUnit GUI:
[image]

2) I use the default setting of NUnit for Shadow Copy:
[image]